# Chrome typeahead menu displaying incorrectly

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome

I just installed `Windows 7 Professional` on my Asus laptop. I then install Google Chrome, version

```
Google Chrome   36.0.1985.125 (Official Build 283153) m
```

I am getting a strange display error when I type in the address bar of chrome. The height of the search prediction or typeahead box seems to be getting set incorrectly.

[image]

Zoomed in:

[image]

Any suggestions? Also, I apologize if I have posted this in the wrong stack exchange network. I am happy to move it.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround for this by selecting 'Disable desktop composition' under Compatibility settings.

I had a similar problem with Mozilla Thunderbird's context menu after installing a complete custom theme. I'm not really sure if they're related, they were both fixed by checking 'Disable desktop composition' under Compatibility settings (reverting to the default theme for Thunderbird also fixed it). It also seems to be happening in Chrome with the boxes showing a link's location when you hover over a link.

Hoping someone else can shed some light on this, and possibly provide a better solution?